# mpic++ main(int, char**) - deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Tags: char, deprecated, program-entry-point, argv, mpic++

during compiling older C++ code on Ubuntu 11.10 with mpic++ ([Open MPI C++ wrapper compiler](http://www.open-mpi.org/)) I got this warning connected with `int main(int argc, char **argv){...}`:

`main(int, char**) : warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`

I tried to edit the code to `int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){...}` but it did not help (contrary to e.g. [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896645/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char)).

What did I wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: It was probably in some code that you haven't shown us.  In C++, the `int` is required, so you should have `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  What happens when you just have an empty program: `int main(int argc, char **arg) { }`?

Comment: If I have an empty program `int main(int argc, char **argv) { }` there is no warning message. In the program (between `{ }` ) I use `argv` on two lines: `#ifdef PARALLEL
 MPI_err = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); #endif
 parameter p(argc, argv); ` In `parameter::parameter(int argc, char **argv)` (where commandline parameters are checked) it is used on these lines `strcpy(my_name,argv[0]); strcpy( input_file_name, argv[1] );`.

Comment: As I suspected, the error was in the code that you replaced with `...`.  Narrow your program down to the minimal *complete* program that reproduces the problem; post that program and the exact error m message you get, clearly indicating the line that the error message refers to.  Do this by editing your question, not in a comment (you can't do proper formatting in comments).